# Sending Data in JSON schema using AT Commands

Tags: c, json, parsing, at-command

I am working on MQTT connection establishment to the server.
I need to send the data to the server in JSON schema format using AT Commands.
The module used in **N58 Neoway** module. Using AT Commands connection got established and for publishing data or subscribing data to/from the server, it should happen in JSON format.
The AT Command used is:

```
AT+MQTTPUB=1,1,<"topic_name">,<"data">
```

I need to send the JSON schema in the place of data.
Looking for any suggestions/help.

The source code is based on C.

Comment: Is JSON style escaping good for the `data` quote escaping format? ... FYI, if you're looking for a soft type system that can be converted to / from JSON, you might look at the FIOBJ from [facil.io](http://facil.io) (I am the author). The next version is being developed at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/facil-io/cstl)

Comment: Did you had a look at [the Neoway N58 manual](http://wless.ru/files/GSM/Neoway/N58/Neoway_N58_AT_Command_Manual_V1_0.pdf)?

Comment: FYI: questions requesting help finding a library are considered off-topic and might be closed. There are better forums / sites for library hunting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in sending JSON through AT commands is that it contains double quotes `"`, that are unfortunately interpreted according to AT commands ETSI specification as the beginning of a string parameter. So, what happens in many modules is that it is impossible so send a JSON string as a parameter.

Some modems vendors solve this issue by starting an *online mode* in which data can be sent rawly.
**N58** uses a different strategy instead, that consists in escaping the special characters. In the [AT command guide](http://wless.ru/files/GSM/Neoway/N58/Neoway_N58_AT_Command_Manual_V1_0.pdf) it is called **data link escape**.

Though the guide could be better (there's not explicit explanation of data link escape), we can infer it from the examples (see for example the one in `AT+UDPSEND`): **in order to escape `"` character, just write `\"` as you would do in a C string**. Example:

```
AT+MQTTPUB=1,1,"topic_name","{\"menu\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"value\":\"2\"}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After using escape sequence the format is working.